# How to run a java class file in windows 10

Tags: java

I crawled through the forums and tried a few things, I am just trying to run a java file I downloaded from github that I did not make. I compiled it fine, but am now stuck. Here's what I've done so far (In the downloads directory for both):

`java.Randomizer`, 
and 
`java -cp C:\Users\enajo\Downloads\Randomizer`

Both resulted in `Error: Could not find or load main class`
The file is located in downloads and is named `Randomizer.class` with the classname being `ca.pogo4545.randomizer`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Questions: what is the fully qualified class name of the class you want to run? Does it have a main method entry point? What dependencies does it have? You may not be able to run it at all, if it has dependencies. And you'll have to ensure that the class is in the right directory structure to match its package name.

Comment: Try running javap against it to see its package and available methods e.g. javap /path/to/your/Randomizer.class.

Answer (score 0):

If you declared a package name (that you mentioned as classname) the run command line must include the name of it:

```
java ca.pogo4545.randomizer.Randomizer
```

But in this case the file also must be in a directory structure that represent the same package, and if you using more than one class you must include the -cp arguments

Answer (score 0):

First of all the name of the class must be the same as the name of the file . 
Java and Javac are case-sensitive.

Compile like : `javac HelloWorldApp.java`

And run like : `java -cp . HelloWorldApp`

Comment: I recompiled it and removed the package name, and it works perfectly now. Thank You

Comment: So you can mark it as answered ! Thank you :)